# Copy the cell above and increment value by 1 (Value is alphabetical)

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I'm new to VBA and could use some help. From the active cell, I need to copy the value from the cell above and increment the value by 1. The value is always two letters such as AA, AB, AC. I can find information on incrementing numbers but not letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim v As String
    v = "CD" 'for example
    Debug.Print Replace(Range(v & "1").Offset(0, 1).Address(0, 0), "1", "") '> CE
End Sub
```

should work for any two-letter combo (but "ZZ" will give you "AAA")

Without the limitations of using range references:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim e
    For Each e In Array("A", "AA", "AZ", "AZZ", "ZZZ", String(10,"Z"))
        Debug.Print e, NextSeq(CStr(e))
    Next e
End Sub

Function NextSeq(s As String)
    Dim rv As String, a As Long, carry As Boolean, ls As Long, i As Long
    ls = Len(s)
    For i = ls To 1 Step -1
        a = Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)) - 64 ' "A"=ASCII 65
        If i = ls Or carry Then
            a = IIf(a = 26, 1, a + 1) 'roll over ?
            carry = a = 1             'carry 1 to next iteration ? 
        End If
        rv = Chr(64 + a) & rv
    Next i
    NextSeq = IIf(carry, "A" & rv, rv) 'one more "A" ?
End Function
```

Output:

```txt
A             B
AA            AB
AZ            BA
AZZ           BAA
ZZZ           AAAA
ZZZZZZZZZZ    AAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Clever use of column addresses! - Fyi You might be interested my alternative post using a byte array. @TimWilliams

Comment: Thank you but I get a compile error when I try to use this.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question to show the code you tried?  You'd need to do something with the result of the expression I posted.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I just want the result of the function to go in the active cell but I can't figure out how to do that. Can you show me how to do that please?

Comment: Like this: `Selection.Value = NextSeq(CStr(Selection.Offset(-1).Value))`

Answer (score 0):

**Byte array approach as start help**

For the sake of the art I demonstrate another approach to "increment" a two-letter combination within a given range from "AA" to "ZZ"; this can be done by incrementing the numeric value of the last|previous letter in a so called **byte array**.

Having declared variable (e.g. `by()`) as of type *Byte*  one can easily assign the string value (e.g. `s`) to it via `by = s`. The used alphabetic letters (A to Z) now show the corresponding numeric character value in element pairs (the first letter value can be taken from `by(0)`, the second=last one from `by(2)` or `by(ubound(by)-1)` as there are 4 elements with indices 0 to 3 here).

```
Public Function IncLetter(Optional ByVal s As String = "AA") As String
    If Len(s) > 2 Or UCase(s) = "ZZ" Then
        IncLetter = s & "?": Exit Function
    End If
'a) get numeric character values
    Dim by() As Byte: by = s
'b) increment last alphabetic letter
    Dim indx As Long: indx = UBound(by) - 1
    'check if last letter is "Z"
    If UCase(Chr(by(indx))) = "Z" Then
        by(indx) = by(indx) - 25
        by(indx - 2) = by(indx - 2) + 1
    Else
        by(indx) = by(indx) + 1
    End If
'c) return new string as function result
    IncLetter = by
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, this returns AB regardless of what letters are currently in the cell. So if the cell is currently SG it should become SH but it gives AB as the result.

Comment: This is because the default input value is "AA", you have to call it via `IncLetter(someCellValue)`, or as direct formula entry like e.g. `=IncLetter(A2)` to pass the correct argument `s`  to the function. If the referred cell value is "SG" you'll get "SH" @NewBe